# Remove CSS file from installed extension?

Tags: extensions, css, xml

I am using **theme254k** Package of **default** Theme of **Magento 1.8.1.0.** I installed an extension. This extension added a CSS file. I would like to remove this CSS file. How can I do that ?

Comment: check in skin folder in extension folder and go to same path in magento folder and remove it.....

Comment: Thanks @BabyinMagento for your reply. Actually I am looking for the XML file where this CSS file included.

Answer (score 0):

go to **app/design/frontend/base or default/layout/modulexml.xml**

remove the code add

```
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>yourcss.css</stylesheet>
```

comment that code

You can find the layout file  **app/code/local or community/spacename/modulename/etc/config.xml** will defined in **frontend > layout**

```
<frontend>
  <layout>
        <updates>
        <test>
            <file>test.xml</file> // here will be layout file name
        </test>
        </updates>
  </layout>
 </frontend>
```